# Find multiple strings in a file scattered over multiple lines using awk

Tags: string, file, awk, line

I am fairly new to `awk`, and was looking for a "oneliner" in `awk` that could help me find files that contain all three strings that are in a file, the strings will be on different lines in the file(s).
I was able to gather from different sites this `awk` command, which looks for the strings "dna-advant", "vty 5 15" and "vty 16 31".
Only if all three strings are found, I wanted it to print only the filename of the file, and that works. But, although it works, I do not understand how it works.

What is the use of FNR ==1? And I do not understand the last part either

```
... { r=1; print FILENAME; nextfile } END { exit 1-r }'
```

Can someone explain it to me? Is there a possible shorter way of doing the same? :-)

```
gawk 'FNR == 1 { s1 = s2 = s3 = 0 }
    /dna-advant/ { s1 = 1 }
    /vty 16 31/ { s2 = 1 } 
    /vty 5 15/ { s3 =1 }  
    s1 && s2 && s3 { r=1; print FILENAME; nextfile }
    END { exit 1-r }' k*
```

I tried using `grep` but I cannot use the `grep -P` on my system, since I am trying to get deeper into how `awk` functions, I really wanted it to work with this command, hopefully someone here can explain how this command works and possibly come up with a shorter version of it!

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FNR==1` means that the following piece of code gets executed on the first line of each file that is opened. That code just resets all the s1/s2/s3 flags as each file is opened.

FNR is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html).

---

The `r` thing is purely for setting the exit status. It sets 0 (success) if one or more files are found, or 1 (failure) if no files are found. This allows it to be used like this:

```
if gawk ... k* ; then ...
```

Or like this:

```
gawk ...
status=$?
...
if [ $status -eq 1 ] ; then
   ...
fi
```

If you don't need/use that construct/functionality, you can omit all the stuff pertaining to `r` and the entire `END` block, but it doesn't cost you much performance and could be useful at some point.

---

The code is already pretty efficient - it stops as soon as possible, reads as little as possible and is easy to read.

You could probably build an alternative version with `grep` along these lines, but I wouldn't bother (and didn't):

```
grep -l 'dna-advant' k* | xargs grep -l 'vty 16 31' | xargs grep -l 'vty 5 15'
```

and optimize by searching for least likely string first.